# How can I get new /etc/samba folder?

Tags: samba, smb

I have manually removed `/etc/samba` folder, hoping that reinstalling Samba would create a fresh one so I could have new `smb.conf` file with default settings.

Is there a way to restore this folder or get a fresh one?

Comment: Was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 4):

You have a copy of your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file in `/usr/share/samba/smb.conf`. So create the `/etc/samba` directory manually using

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/samba
```

and then copy the required file using:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/samba/smb.conf /etc/samba
```

[(Source)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1691231)